# Swipe to delete from TableView not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I simply want to add the "swipe-to-delete-function" to my `tableView` and as far as I know the only thing I have to add are these two functions:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        self.deleteWishDelegate?.deleteWish(indexPath)
    }
}
```

But this doesn't do anything. I can not swipe. A weird thing that I noticed is that my whole `View` has a `TransitionView`  on top of it, which I have no idea where it comes from. However I can click a `Button` inside a `tableViewCell` so I don't think its blocking anything.

Any one any idea what is going on here? If you need more details just let me know.

**Update:**

As suggested in the comments I used another function to get the job done:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Löschen") { _, _, completionHandler in
        self.deleteWishDelegate?.deleteWish(indexPath)
    completionHandler(true)
    }
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = .red
    deleteAction.image = UIImage(systemName: "trash")
    let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
    configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
    return configuration
}
```

And my delteWsihDelegate-function:

```
extension WishlistViewController: DeleteWishDelegate {
    func deleteWish(_ idx: IndexPath){
        // remove the wish from the user's currently selected wishlist
        wishList.wishes.remove(at: idx.row)
        // set the updated data as the data for the table view
        theTableView.wishData.remove(at: idx.row)
        self.theTableView.tableView.deleteRows(at: [idx], with: .right)
        print("deleted")
    }
}
```

The problem is now that that only works every 20-30 times I swipe. Anyone know why this can happens?

**Update 2**

I found out what the problem was. I have another `GestureRecognizer` on the same view. After deleting that the function works perfectly fine.  Is there any way to have both working at the same time?

Comment: try to use `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?`

Comment: Why you have used "override" on "commit editingStyle" method of a table view. It can be used without override property.

Comment: @Kirow what do I return there?

Comment: @AshutoshkumarMishra because I am in subclass of TableViewController

Comment: Are you using UITableViewController or UIViewController class?

Comment: @AshutoshkumarMishra `class WhishlistTableViewController: UITableViewController`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UITableViewDelegate` implements the method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

which can be used to configure a swipe action - a delete in your case. Here is a example I use in one of my projects:

```
extension ExampleViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive,
                                              title: "Delete") { [weak self] _, _, complete in
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            complete(true)
        }
        deleteAction.backgroundColor = .red

        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
    }

    // instead of a gesture recognizer you can use this delegate method
    // it will be called whenever you tap on a cell
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // whatever you gesture recognizer did
    }
}
```

Since your GestureRecognizer on the entire view gives you trouble, I'll recommend using a third party implementation or apples public API to handle dismissing your viewController instead of implementing it yourself. In that case you can use the UIModalPresentationStyle of your viewController.

```
func startExampleViewController() {
   exampleViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
   previousViewController.present(exampleViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, could you have a look at my **Update** in the question ?

Comment: Have you tried running that delegate method on the main thread? I'm not entirely sure how your delegates are structured, but a success every 20-30 times indicates to a delay in an animation or to a race condition on when your delegate is set.

Comment: @Chris as I see your update just now. Have you considered removing the GestureRecognizer right before the deletion actions started?

Comment: I think youre understanding it wrong. Its not about the deletion of the data. I cant even "swipe-to-delete" if I have the other GestureRecognzier there as well

Comment: @Chris A yes I see. Okay, I updated my answer saying that you should not use a gesture recognizer on a tableViewCell but a delegate methods designed for that task instead

Comment: not quite sure if that is doing the trick. Let me explain you my setup: I have a `ViewController` in which I have a `GestureRecognizer` on the whole `View`. In that `VC` I have a `custom TableViewController`:  `class WhishlistTableViewController: UITableViewController` .

Comment: Alright. Having a GestureRecognizer on a whole view is kind of an Anti-Pattern. Your TableView seems to be setuped correctly. Finding the right configuration for your gesture recognizer should be your main goal right now.

Comment: yes my tableView works fine if I remove the other GR but what the best way to resolve this now ?

Comment: That your tableView works is a good foundation. So now what does your GestureRecognizer exaclty do? Why did you implement it that way and what problem solves your implementation?

Comment: I implemented it to dismiss the View. If the user slides down (outside the tableView) the ViewController gets dismissed

Comment: I understand. I recommend using a third party package like 'FloatingPanel' (https://github.com/SCENEE/FloatingPanel) or apples own implementation. When you push a new viewController onto the view hierarchy you can define a presentationStyle. In your case the 'formSheet' style seems quite fitting. You can look into the official docs here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle. I'll update my answer with a short example which hopefully helps you to get going in that topic.

Comment: I know what youre saying but its not why I need in my case.

Comment: Okay. What do you think would fit best in your case? As far as I understood you want to dismiss the view yourself?

Comment: its quite hard to understand without seeing it. I am using a `Hero-Animation`

Comment: You're right. Without seeing the project and implementation I'm afraid I can't help you any further at this point. My next ideas where to let go of the 'swipe down' gesture and use a different approach on dismissing your current viewController.

Comment: Thats why Im doing for now. The slide down gesture was just a nice addon I liked

Comment: Good luck and happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

*I have implemented delete action in the UITableViewController, Use the following code:-*

```
class TestTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var arrData =  ["test1", "test111", "test11121", "test1121", "test121", "test1123", "test13213", "test165342", ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return arrData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TestTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TestTableViewCell
        cell.title.text = arrData[indexPath.row]
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            arrData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but can you have a look at my updated question ?

Comment: I have used your "trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt" method in our project it works perfectly.  Could you add the code of "self.deleteWishDelegate?.deleteWish(indexPath)" method.

Comment: "extension WishlistViewController: DeleteWishDelegate", I think you should change "WishlistViewController" class name in your extension  with "WhishlistTableViewController".  Beacuse in the top comment you have used "WhishlistTableViewController" as UITableViewController